# JAVA Название аргументов для интерфейсов после компиляции

Tags: java, компиляция, документация, code-style

После компиляции аргументы методов у интерфейса меняют своё название на varN(var1,var2,str1 etc)
Я хочу сделать библиотеку, и что бы при реализации интерфейсов из этой библиотеки, я видел корректные имена аргументов. 
Т.е я хочу что бы после компиляции и подключения либы в другом проекте, я могу видеть аругументы методов и конструкторов, и мог видеть что за int or String запрашивает метод.

Как это можно сделать ?
Я знаю что можно при компиляции можно указать "javac -g:vars", но мне не нужно сохранять названия внутри методов, а только публичных методов и конструкторов. И повлияет ли это на производительность кода в дальнейшем?

Например интересно как это в других либах делают, что я когда использую их интерфейсы, я могу прочитать что они запрашивают.

Буду безумно рад помощи, так как вопрос очень беспокоит а ответов почти нет.

Comment: Пишут JavaDoc + исходники прикладывают. Если не хотят выкладывать все исходники, тогда разбивают на несколько, например mylib api и mylib core. В первой интерфейсы/енумы, во второй реализация, для первой выкладывают сырцы, для второй нет.

Comment: Это выглядит очень здорово, спасибо!
А можно какой нибудь источник для премера как это делают ?
Или какое нибудь подробное описание ?
Тоесть ты описывал либу в стиле javaDoc, описал интерфесы и методы, а после упаковал в один jar ?
Или гинерируешь javaDoc и либу компилируешь с "javac -g:vars" что бы остались названия в аргументах ?
Тоесть мне именно интересен сам процесс...